# Equivalent operator in IBM COGNOS for 'for each' and 'for all' in SAP BO

Tags: reporting, business-intelligence, cognos

I am looking for an equivalent to context operator in SAP BO viz `for each` and `for all` in IBM COGNOS.

My SAP BO expression is as follows:

```
If([UTR Deliv Qty]-[UTR Final Order Qty]<>0;1;0)ForEach([UTR Order Dat];[tracking 1].[UTR Item];[tracking 1].[UTR Loc])
```

I want to build an equivalent COGNOS xpression

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain what ForEach is doing in this case? Will you be running this from a relational source or a cube source?

Comment: A quick reading of ForEach makes it seem like it is most similar to a SQL group by. With that in mind, Cognos is essentially a SQL generator. Create a query with Date, Item, Location (ensure they are set as attributes in the model) along with your two measures (again, make sure they are set as measures). Create a calculated measure of Delivery-Final Order. Drag them all onto the report and run it. Cognos will auto-aggregate measures. Let us know how this differs from what you're expecting.